# There is no real $3\times3$ matrix $A$ for which $A^2=-I$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm asked to prove or disprove this but I'm stuck.
I feel like this is actually true but i'm not sure as to how I can formulate a proof for this statement. Any leads?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $AA  = -I_3$, then

$\det(AA) = \det(-I_3) $

Does this help?

Comment: This does help, thank you. Now i can make det(A)^2 = -1 which is not possible, correct?

Comment: @ShaniVl exactly that